# What are the next steps for websocket load testing in JMETER?

Tags: websocket, jmeter, load-testing

I followed some steps and
Added Thread Group > Websocket Open Connection > Websocket Request Response Sampler> View Result Tree
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bh7RA.png
For above scenario
I am getting this Response code:302 Response message:Got unexpected status 302 with statusLine:HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Can you please help me to resolve this?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXQSC.png

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your setup is correct, it looks like you're getting a [HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP) response with [HTTP 302 status](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/302) and presumably this response contains [Location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Location) header containing your WebSocket endpoint.

You need to extract it using [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) or [Boundary Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-boundary-extractor) or more suitable [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) and use it in your WebSocket Open Connection sampler, this way you should be able to use correct host/port/path.